# Add login / logout to drupal menu that's not a primary or secondary menu

Tags: drupal, authentication, drupal-6, menu, append

Im trying to append an item to a menu that I created.

I know its get the primary and secondary menus using "menu_secondary_local_tasks()" etc, and then add items within preprocess page. How would I go about this with a menu that I created?

Here is the code I am using to check is the user is logged in...

```
function themeName_check_login() {
    global $user;
    if ($user->uid) {   
        print l("Log out, " . $user->name,"logout");
    } else {
        print l("Log In ","user");
    }   
}
```

Thanks in advance,
-Matt

Answer (score 1):

If you call [menu_navigation_links](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_navigation_links/6) with the name of your menu, you should get an array of links formatted for the current page, which you can then easily add to before display.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to verify if the user is logged in; the login link will not be visible to users who are already logged in, and the logout link will not be visible to users who are not logged in.